# Is there a way to change and save the default values of the attributes so they are used for all new objects that are created in the future?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, attributes

Is there a way to change and save the default values of the attributes so they are used for all new objects that are created in the future?

Example:
Once I create and style a button or textfield for a project, I would like all additional buttons to have the same style.  Instead, every new button, text box, etc created has Xcode's default properties.  Having to set the attributes for every new object is exhausting.  Is there a way to save a created object as the "new" default of that object type...at least for the current project.

I have tried using the IBDesignables and IBInspectable but that simply creates new attributes.  In fact the new attributes don't even display the default values assigned when viewing the attributes inspector.  When changing an existing property in the inspector, such as backgrounds or borders, it creates a totally separate attribute and then it is confusing which attribute overrides which.

Another example:
I would like textfields set to a certain size with a certain font, size and color, borders, rounded corners, etc.  This would be the default but on my story boards, I may wish to change the width or other properties not set in the defaults.

I have tried to search using hundreds of different terms but nothing matches what I am asking.  It can't be that difficult????  Yes, I am a bit of a nub when it comes to Xcode and swift.  All the other coding tools I can think of have a provision for setting defaults when creating new objects.

Comment: Take look at property wrappers in the docs.Swift.org language guide. I haven’t worked with them *yet* but have been reading up on them and think they should be able to handle this easily

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is called Subclasssing.  You make a new class that inherits from the class you want to extend, and then do your custom settings on it.  You can use your subclass in Storyboard by setting the custom class in the Identity Inspector, if you want to be able to set properties from Storyboard then you can add them via `@IBInspectable` and have that property set the actual property.  If you don't need to see the custom settings in storyboard then it's easier to just set the value in views initialization.

```
@IBDesignable
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set { self.layer.cornerRadius = newValue }
        get { self.layer.cornerRadius }
    }
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        set { super.layer.borderColor = newValue?.cgColor }
        get { UIColor(cgColor: self.layer.borderColor ?? UIColor.black.cgColor) }
    }
    override var borderStyle: UITextField.BorderStyle {
        set { super.borderStyle = .none }
        get { .none }
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setupView()
    }
    func setupView() {
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12)
        self.textAlignment = .center
        self.placeholder = "My custom placeholder text"
        self.layer.borderWidth = 3
    }
}
```

[image: subclass]
[image: custom properties]
[image: simulator]

Comment: that’s a great answer. The more I learn Swift the more I like it.